# Tetragrammaton in Non-Jewish Books

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally, kedusha-holiness, shemos-sacred-names

If there was a New Testament in Hebrew and it contained the Tetragrammaton in it, how would you get rid of it? Obviously it cannot be buried next to Sifrei Torah or other Holy works.

Comment: `Obviously it cannot be buried next to Sifrei Torah or other Holy works.` Source? Remember that many seemingly obvious things are much more complex, in reality

Comment: Either burn it or cut out the tetragrammaton and burn the rest

Comment: @sabbahillel - G-d's Name in the form of the Tetragrammaton appears many times in a Hebrew NT so one would be sitting there for hours!

Comment: @mevaqesh - I mean the NT, not just Hashem's Name from it. Obviously if you cut out all the shemos and burned the rest you could bury it next to Sifrei Torah

Comment: @EzraHoerster I repeat my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Gemara Gittin 45b:

> R`Nahman said: We have it on tradition that a scroll of the Law which has been written by a Min should be burnt

meaning with all the shemot.

This is stated in SA YD 281, 1:

> ספר תורה שכתבו אפיקורוס -- ישרף.

This concerns good contents written by bad person,  so bad contents need to be even less "kadoch". No need to bury it.

Comment: My prior comments were deleted. To repeat the main points, this does not explain why the Torah scroll of a "min" is to be destroyed and it is therefore very difficult to know whether or not this ruling applies to the case at hand. Additionally, the OP never said that the book in question was written by a "min", making this answer even poorer.